# Найти и вырезать элемент

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

На странице 1 выводится страница 2 в `<iframe>`.

На странице 2 имеется элемент `<div id="music_mini_vk"></div>`

Как на странице 1 найти этот элемент в `<iframe>` и вырезать?

Comment: Взаимодействовать с кодом `iframe` можно только если страница отображаемая в нём находиться на Вашем сайте.

Answer (score 0):

```
let element=$("iframe").contents().find("#music_mini_vk").detach()
```

На JS попробуйте так:

```
let iframe=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0],
iframeContent=iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow.document,
element=iframeContent.getElementById('music_mini_vk')
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

Comment: А на JS как подобное выполнить?

Comment: @DenisHeavenly обновил, опробуйте

Comment: Не удаляется элемент

Comment: @DenisHeavenly во-первых, сайт, который вы загружаете в iframe находится на вашем же домене? Если нет, то на него нельзя воздействовать. Во-вторых, вы уверены, что запускаете код после того, как сайт в iframe полностью загрузился?

Comment: Нет. Сайт находится на другом домене.